# JavaScript inline validation in php code

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I want to validate a textfield with javascript. Here is my code in php:

```
$question_type = "<input type='text' id='question_type_n' onkeyup="allnumeric(this.value)" name='question_type_n_".$qid."' value='".$d[0]."' >";
```

I also have the function allnumeric() in javascript. But it returns errors. 
Javascript-Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'allnumeric' (T_STRING) in E:\Share\xampp\htdocs\Dropbox\icsurvey\application\views\finish_survey.php on line 142
```

Comment: I think your problem is with nested quotes. Try single quotes instead.. `$question_type = "<input type='text' id='question_type_n' onkeyup='allnumeric(this.value)' name='question_type_n_".$qid."' value='".$d[0]."' >";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `onkeyup="allnumeric(this.value)"` use in single  quotes
like `onkeyup='allnumeric(this.value)'`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @user503413 This does provide a solution. Simple solutions are still answers.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek - thank you for your feedback, you could have used the time to edit the question to add some simple explanation why the provided code snippet would provide a solution and what was wrong in what the poster tried. And also, if you consider it that good as a response next to the question there is a up-vote button you can express your opinion in that way.

Comment: @user503413 I'm simply stating that this is a valid answer, such that it provides a solution like the other answers. Not that it is a good answer, simply that it's not violating the rules. I don't think this is a good response, because the lack of explanation. And there is no need to edit because there are already better responses to this question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape it properly

```
$question_type = "<input type='text' id='question_type_n' onkeyup='allnumeric(this.value)' name='question_type_n_".$qid."' value='".$d[0]."' >";
```

First thing is that you dint concatenate the string properly. Second error being php wont understand the js function `allnumeric`. You have to embed it as string so that it will be triggered on the onclick event on your browser not at the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

PHP outputs HTML, in which can contain JavaScript. Note you need to use `.` to concatenate in PHP. But in this case we just need to use single quotes:

```
$question_type = "<input ... onkeyup='allnumeric(this.value)' ... >";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your PHP code:

```
$question_type = "<input type='text' id='question_type_n' onkeyup='allnumeric(this.value)' name='question_type_n_".$qid."' value='".$d[0]."' >";
```